# ExUnit mock sequence

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

Is it possible to mock a sequence of return values with ExUnit Mock the same way meck provides this functionality in Erlang?

```
...
meck:new(my_module),
meck:sequence(my_module, method, 1, [Response1, Response2]),
meck:unload(module),
...
```

If not, is it possible to successfully combine meck and mock in the same unit test ExUnit Elixir module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no mention of `:meck.sequence` in [`mock.ex`](https://github.com/jjh42/mock/blob/7f2251f781f646a08bb65c85c215f107c9627435/lib/mock.ex) so I'm guessing this is not supported yet.

It should be fine to call `:meck` functions directly as long as it's outside a `Mock.with_mock` call and you make sure to call `:meck.unload/1` after you're done. (And you use `async: false`, as Mock already requires.) This should be fine even in the same test.

```
test "the truth" do
  url = "http://www.google.com"

  :meck.new(HTTPoison)
  :meck.sequence(HTTPoison, :get!, 1, [%{body: "foo"}, %{body: "bar"}])
  assert HTTPoison.get!(url).body == "foo"
  assert HTTPoison.get!(url).body == "bar"
  assert HTTPoison.get!(url).body == "bar"
  :meck.unload(HTTPoison)

  assert HTTPoison.get!(url).body =~ "HTML"

  with_mock HTTPoison, [get!: fn(_url) -> %{body: "baz"} end] do
    assert HTTPoison.get!(url).body == "baz"
  end

  assert HTTPoison.get!(url).body =~ "HTML"
end
```

Demo:

```
$ mix test
.

Finished in 0.2 seconds
1 test, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mock library has `in_series/2` helper which allows to mock sequence of calls.

Here is excerpt from [the docs](https://github.com/jjh42/mock#mock-repeated-calls) and [related PR](https://github.com/jjh42/mock/pull/132) adding this featre.

```
defmodule MyTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false

  import Mock

  test "mock repeated calls with in_series" do
    with_mock String,
      [slice: [in_series(["test", 1..3], ["string1", "string2", "string3"])]]
    do
      assert String.slice("test", 1..3) == "string1"
      assert String.slice("test", 1..3) == "string2"
      assert String.slice("test", 1..3) == "string3"
    end
  end
end
```

the other way to achieve the same result would be

```
with_mock(Ecto.UUID, generate: [
  {[], :meck.seq(["uuid-1", "uuid-2"])}
]) do
  Ecto.UUID.generate() # => "uuid-1"
end
```